# Can we have a static block within a main block i tried and got an error

Tags: java

In netbeans I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -    illegal start of expression
    at javaapplication3.NewClass4.main(NewClass4.java:20)
```

My code:

```
public class NewClass4
{
   public static void main(String a[])
   {
      System.out.println("hello");
      static
      {
          System.out.println("u");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a) illegal syntax and b) meaningless. What do you think you are achieving with the `static` block inside a method?

Comment: I think the fact that you get an error when you try that should give you a *very* good hint as to whether it is legal.

Answer (score 2):

static block is executed when the class is loaded. Mostly used for initializing static variables. You can have static block anywhere inside class body. But not inside a method

For eg, for a singleton class you can use it to initialize the instance

```
public class SingletonClass {

   private static SingletonClass instance;

   static {
      instance = new SingletonClass();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move it outside your main method:

```
    public class NewClass4
      {
          static
          {
              System.out.println("u");
          }

       public static void main(String a[])
       {
          System.out.println("hello");

        }
      }
```